# Is it possible to integrate Action Script 3.0 with Java Script and PHP for an online browser game?

Tags: architecture, actionscript-3, javascript, php

My client wants a browser based online game, languages which are known to me are Java Script PHP and Action Script and also My Sql.

Game is quite like Farmvile as far as functionality is concerned.I would like to know how to combine these technologies to make a full fledged browser game, also do i have to use all of these languages or AS 3.0 with PHP and MySql will be enough?

Lastly i would like to know is there any book,link or tutorial about architectures and framework of games like farmvile?

Thank You

Comment: You don't know the basic capabilities of your tools, yet you are selling services? As far as I understand your situation you might as well be wanting to build a house and then ask how nails and hammers interact. I can write an answer explaining the basics of tool choice for the job, but I doubt that will get you far in your project.

Comment: I appreciate your reply.I have made games in AS 3.0 but never an online game so i agree i do not know how to integrate it with other languages or database?

Comment: I think your question is a bit vague. Sure you can integrate them, but there's an obvious connection between flash+php/mysql - integrating flash with javascript to create a game - which is supposed to do what here? Both have too large of an overlap in problems they address, so there's too large a gray area for your question to be receive a satisfying answer

Comment: give the guy a break, at least he came here to learn.  he just doesn't know what questions to ask

Comment: why is this not removed yet?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a game that uses a Flash/AS3 front end and a communicates with a backend PHP/MySQL Server through dynamic XML sheets (might not be the best way) on a shared server through a local hosting company.

In general:
1. Load ActionScript with configurations variables using JavaScript (swfObject.js)
2. Have AS3 game connect by writing and reading XML (contacting per-specified pages)
3. Use PHP pages to act as intermediary, take in values passed from Flash/AS front end and perform database operations.
4. PHP code generates XML response.
5. AS3 reads XML File and processes data
...now you have a possible two-player/transactional game

Facebook has a pretty easy PHP API to use for integrating games and pulling in user data (name, friends, etc...). Check out the Facebook Developers areas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either ActionScript/Flash or JavaScript/HTML for the front-end. You'll be doing pretty much the same in either case, that is using HTTP connections for interacting with the back-end.

For the back-end you can use pretty much any language and database that you like. This could be PHP and MySQL, which is an easy to use choice, though with a pretty bad performance.

Other obvious choices for programming could be Node.js or .NET/C#. But really, anything where you can get a good HTTP library is within scope. For database you can choose anything that has an interface in the chosen language.

Comment: I am a designer mainly and a casual programmer, by my client i meant my companies client, in the project i am doing the designing part and coding part will be handled by other team,I asked the question because I was curious to know since i use AS 2 and 3 a lot for Animation,sorry for asking the question in a bad way and thanks for your replies,Its quite clear now.By the way what other choices do i have for back-end programming instead of PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Now I wonder why you ask here rather than just go talking with the programmers, I'm sure they can bring you up to speed, and they probably have their own preferences. Is any of this your decision? Otherwise, why do you ask?

Comment: I asked here because i was thinking to create a complete project of my own which will add up to my portfolio.I did not asked my fellow programmers because its something related to my personal project which i did not wanted to share with them.No the decision regarding my companies project is not mine,but for my own project it is.

Comment: So, what kind of programming have you done? If you are new to game programming you shouldn't do anything networked, and you should stick to a single language for a while.

Comment: No as i told you i have done programming in AS 2.0 and 3.0 but only small stuff like animations, games like skating etc. also i know Java and Java Script HTML etc. but not PHP i am learning it.Also i have some experience in building websites with HTML CSS and Java Script.

Comment: Then, where do you want to grow better? Use those tools. Still, if you are going for your first network code you should probably keep it at a low level, make the simplest possible multi-player game that you can.

Comment: Saying you "know Java" makes everyone realize how much you don't know. Nobody who is experienced with Java would say outright that they "know" it.

Comment: What do you mean by that?sorry i did not get you?

Comment: If you meant that Java is too big to know everything of it.Yes you are right i do not know complete Java, but I am a computer science graduate and i have done several live projects in Java including JSP,socket programming etc. so i know a bit of it and i meant that when i said i know Java.Its because i did my Masters in Design and Animation which entirely changed my field and i had been working in this field from past 5 years i am a bit out of touch from those technologies and need a little brush up thats it.